# How can I stop phusion passenger standalone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, phusion

I don't know how to stop phusion passenger standalone. I have 2 instances running one at port 8000 and other at 8001. Can anybody give me idea how can I stop passenger on each proxy. cause I just need one at 8001. And because there are two instances, it's taking up double memory. Please help me, I am on dreamhost vps.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this

```
passenger stop -p 8000
```

or

```
passenger stop --pid-file tmp/pids/passenger.pid
```

Comment: Just mentioning that using the -p you should be in the same directory that started the process.

Answer (score 1):

```
passenger stop --pid-file tmp/pids/passenger.8000.pid
```

And

```
passenger stop --pid-file tmp/pids/passenger.8001.pid
```

will stop both the servers on these two ports.